# Divs animation inside a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, animation

Is that possible animating a flexbox after changing "order" of divs? I searched a lot on the web, but I didn't find any solution. I have just found "-webkit-animation: slide-down .6s ease-out;" which cause a sliding down for all items. The result I wish to obtain is that the current div slides (with animation) to its new position, automatically calculated by the browser, changing its "order" attribute. I mean: if the current div (order: 3) is in (0,0), I change its order by clicking a button, which sets "order: 6". Now the flexbox will automatically move the current div to a new position (for example (10,5)). Is that possible to animate this shift? Thanks in advance. (The container div has multiple rows and columns, so the divs can shift both up and down and both right and left). Thanks in advance.

Comment: No that is not possible. And will never be because of the way css works. You have to use absolute position or something for that.

Comment: Do you mean that some divs are set in a main container? and you want to animate them? do you have any sample code to replicate the situation

Comment: yep, after changing their "order" attribute.

Comment: Cool, please upload some sample here, or on codepen,jsfiddle or codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

I wish to animate the divs while they change position.

```js
function sort()
{
  var childDivs = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName('div');
  for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
  {
    var childDiv = childDivs[i];
    childDiv.style.order = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
  }
}
```

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1pt black solid;
  width: 360px;
}
 
.element
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

button
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px 130px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sort()">Mix</button>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="element" style="background-color: yellow; order: 1">
  </div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: blue; order: 2">
  </div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: red; order: 3">
  </div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: green; order: 4">
  </div> 
  <div class="element" style="background-color: pink; order: 5">
  </div> 
  <div class="element" style="background-color: purple; order: 6">
  </div> 
  <div class="element" style="background-color: turquoise; order: 7">
  </div> 
  <div class="element" style="background-color: gray; order: 8">
  </div> 
  <div class="element" style="background-color: orange; order: 9">
  </div> 
</div>
```